# Number of real roots of given equation

Tags: systems-of-equations, roots

> Eqn is $2x^5 -8x + 7$ = 0
>
> How many real roots does this equation have?
>
> Is there any specific way to solve questions like this?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Sturm chains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem)

Comment: Two positive real roots and one negative real root by [Descartes' rule of signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs)

Comment: @Bumblebee It appears to me that Descartes' rule does not exclude the possibility that there aren't any positive roots.

Comment: Which course should I look up to learn theorems like this? I currently have studied calculus- partial, differential & vector. Please help.

Comment: this is curve sketching, using first derivative, from beginning calculus.

Comment: Numerical Analysis might be useful. It usually contains root-finding algorithms and may also include algorithms to calculate/estimate the number of roots of polynomials.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli: Exactly. Thank you for pointing out that possibility.

Answer (score 1):

We can apply the big gun of [Sturm's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem). The Sturm Chain for $2x^5-8x+7$ is
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
p(x)&p(-\infty)&p(+\infty)\\
2x^5-8x+7&-\infty&+\infty\\
10x^4-8&+\infty&+\infty\\
\frac{32}5x-7&-\infty&+\infty\\
-\frac{3308821}{524288}&-\frac{3308821}{524288}&-\frac{3308821}{524288}\\
\text{sign changes}&2&1
\end{array}
$$
Thus, there is $2-1=1$ real root of $2x^5-8x+7$.

Comment: Thank you. Which course should I look up to learn theorems like this? Currently, I've studied calculus- differential, partial, integral & vector.

Comment: This is not much more than algebra. It might be covered in a real interesting algebra course, but it requires no calculus.

Comment: Linear Algebra course would do?

Comment: No calculus?  The first polynomial in the chain is the derivative?

Comment: @fleablood: ah, yes. I forgot about that. It does require a derivative. After that, it's essentially Euclid's Algorithm.

Comment: @Singh: fleablood mentions that a derivative is required to get the second term in the Sturm Chain. So this would need to be somewhere after calculus, but the bulk of the algorithm is simply division of polynomials.

Comment: Thank you robjohn & fleablood

Comment: The concept of derivatives as slopes (which are instantaneous rates of change) and the derivation of the derivative of polynomials, on the other hand, although calculus, is a basic concept that ought to be accessible to a secong year high-school algebra student.

Answer (score 0):

For $x\geq0$ by AM-GM we obtain
$$2x^5-8x+7=2x^5+4\cdot\frac{7}{4}-8x\geq5\sqrt[5]{2x^5\left(\frac{7}{4}\right)^4}-8x\geq0.$$
For $x<0$ we can use the Descartes rule (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs) , which gives that our equation has one real root.

Comment: Yes! One real root. My answer was correct. I can't tell you how happy I am, but I'll also learn it now. Thank you so much! Is it part of linear algebra? Which course should I look up for theorems like this? Please tell...

Comment: I added the link about the  Descartes rule.

Comment: But which course should I look up to learn theorems like this? I've currently studied calculus- differential, partial & vector.

Comment: It's a known fact in polynomials. AM-GM it's calculus.

Comment: Linear algebra course then?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: Then, please suggest. Which college course should I join for this? Also thanks for your help.

Comment: You are welcome. I learn it in my school.

Comment: Ohh okay thanks. Any good books for Mathematics? I want to learn every theorem like this.

Comment: See my link. About AM-GM see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means

Comment: This inequality I know

Answer (score 0):

a polynomial should have a local extrema between two consecutive real roots. This is quite intuitive if you try to draw the graph of the polynomial. If the graph intersects the $x$-axis from below at $x_0$, then it is increasing in a neighbourhood of $x_0$, and it should decrease if it has to cut the $x$-axis again at some point to the right of $x_0$. So the graph has an extrema where it changes from increasing to decreasing. You can reason similarly if the graph cuts the $x$-axis from below. Thus between any two roots of the polynomial $p(x)$, we should have a root for $p^{\prime}(x)$, where $p^{\prime}(x)$ is the derivative of $p(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Forget the $7$ for the moment. $2x^5 - 8 x$ has derivative $10x^4 - 8.$ This is zero at $\pm \sqrt[4] \frac{4}{5},$ where the fourth root is a little smaller than $1.$ At the critical points, the value $$ |2x(x^4 - 4)| = 2|x (\frac{4}{5}- 4)| = 2 |x| \frac{16}{5} = \frac{32|x|}{5} < \frac{32}{5} < 7 \; . $$
In particular, at the critical point with $x > 0,$ the value of $2x^5 - 8 x > -7,$ so $2x^5 - 8x + 7 > 0.$ No root with $x > 0.$ Just one with $x < - \sqrt[4] \frac{4}{5} \; .$

You can download pdfs of graph paper at [GRAPH PAPER](https://www.printablepaper.net/category/graph) Easier suggestion: graph $x^3 - 3x.$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If continuous $f(x)$ has a local extrema at $a$ and at $b>a$ and none between, then $f(x)$ is is either increasing of decreasing on $[a,b]$ and thus $f(x)$ will cross the $x$ axis at most once.  So $f$ has *at most* one root in $[a,b]$.

Let $f(x)= 2x^5 - 8x + 7$.

$f'(x) = 10x^4 - 8$.

$f'(x) = 10x^4 -8 = 0$ would mean $x = \pm \sqrt[4]{\frac 45}$.

So if $f(x)$ has any real roots there acan be at most three of them and they can only occur at:

1) At most one where $x \le -\sqrt[4]{\frac 45}$

2) At most one where $-\sqrt[4]{\frac 45} \le x \le \sqrt[4]{\frac 45}$.

3) At most one where $x \ge \sqrt[4]{\frac 45}$.

It is easy to confirm.

1) $f(-\sqrt[4]{\frac 45}) < 0$ and $f'(x) > 0$ for $x < -\sqrt[4]{\frac 45}$ so that means $f(x) < 0$ for all $x \le -\sqrt[4]{\frac 45}$ so there are no roots there.

2) $f(-\sqrt[4]{\frac 45}) < 0$ but $f(\sqrt[4]{\frac 45}) > 0 $ so there must be exactly one  real root there.

3) $f(\sqrt[4]{\frac 45}) > 0$ and for $x > \sqrt[4]{\frac 45}$, $f'(x)> 0$ so $f$ is increasing so there are no roots there.

So exactly one real root.

Comment: Thank you. This is the process I tried first, but got confused in intervals. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Singh I added a graph to my (similar) answer. Learning how to sketch graphs yourself, rather than making a computer do it, is probably the most valuable skill that is, well, losing ground to technology. Doing it yourself teaches you things.

Comment: Any good books for learning graphs? I'm all in to learn. I just need to know where to look up. Also any other course you could suggest.

Comment: @Singh if you want someone to realize that you intend a comment for them, begin it with an at sign, followed (no spaces) with at least three beginning letters from the username.  Curve sketching will be in any calculus book, you just need to get, or print out, some graph paper, and draw some graphs.